# Strange MYSQL query issue after import process

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have what I thought was a perfect copy of a database.  Unfortunately, a particular query is now massively slower.  These are query analysis images produced by MySQL Workbench. You can see that in the bottom (slower) the order of joins is different and that seems to be the bottleneck.  I have no idea what would cause that join order to change.  Does anyone have any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Query:

```
SELECT 
    mutation.ENTREZ_GENE_ID AS entrezGeneId,
    gene.HUGO_GENE_SYMBOL AS hugoGeneSymbol,
    COUNT(*) AS totalCount,
    COUNT(DISTINCT (mutation.SAMPLE_ID)) AS numberOfAlteredCases
FROM
    mutation
        INNER JOIN
    mutation_event ON mutation_event.MUTATION_EVENT_ID = mutation.MUTATION_EVENT_ID
        AND mutation_event.MUTATION_TYPE != 'Fusion'
        INNER JOIN
    genetic_profile ON mutation.GENETIC_PROFILE_ID = genetic_profile.GENETIC_PROFILE_ID
        INNER JOIN
    sample ON mutation.SAMPLE_ID = sample.INTERNAL_ID
        INNER JOIN
    gene ON mutation.ENTREZ_GENE_ID = gene.ENTREZ_GENE_ID
WHERE
    mutation.SAMPLE_ID IN (SELECT 
            sample.INTERNAL_ID
        FROM
            sample
                INNER JOIN
            patient ON sample.PATIENT_ID = patient.INTERNAL_ID
                INNER JOIN
            genetic_profile ON patient.CANCER_STUDY_ID = genetic_profile.CANCER_STUDY_ID
        WHERE
            genetic_profile.STABLE_ID = 'ccle_broad_2019_mutations'
                AND sample.STABLE_ID IN (...)
                AND sample.INTERNAL_ID = mutation.SAMPLE_ID
                AND genetic_profile.GENETIC_PROFILE_ID = mutation.GENETIC_PROFILE_ID)
GROUP BY mutation.ENTREZ_GENE_ID
```

EXPLAIN ON SLOW DB with very truncated list of samples:

```
+=====================================================================+======================================================================+=======+
|                   Query execution plan on DB2  (Slow)               |                   Query execution plan on DB1                        | Same? |
+=====================================================================+======================================================================+=======+
| id : 1,                                                             | id : 1,                                                              | Yes   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
| select_type : SIMPLE,                                               | select_type : SIMPLE,                                                | Yes   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
| table : mutation,                                                   | table : mutation,                                                    | Yes   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
| partitions : null,                                                  | partitions : null,                                                   | Yes   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
| type : ref,                                                         | type : ref,                                                          | Yes   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
| possible_keys : UQ_MUTATION_EVENT_ID_GENETIC_PROFILE_ID_SAMPLE_ID,  | possible_keys : UQ_MUTATION_EVENT_ID_GENETIC_PROFILE_ID_SAMPLE_ID,   |       |
|       GENETIC_PROFILE_ID,GENETIC_PROFILE_ID_2,GENETIC_PROFILE_ID_3, |        GENETIC_PROFILE_ID,GENETIC_PROFILE_ID_2,GENETIC_PROFILE_ID_3, |       |
|       ENTREZ_GENE_ID,SAMPLE_ID,MUTATION_EVENT_ID,                   |        ENTREZ_GENE_ID,SAMPLE_ID,MUTATION_EVENT_ID,                   | Yes   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
| key : GENETIC_PROFILE_ID,                                           | key : GENETIC_PROFILE_ID_2,                                          | No    |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
| key_len : 4,                                                        | key_len : 8,                                                         | No    |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
| ref : const,                                                        | ref : const,cgds_public.sample.INTERNAL_ID,                          | No    |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
| rows : 792,                                                         | rows : 68,                                                           | No    |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
| filtered : 0.01,                                                    | filtered : 100.00,                                                   | No    |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
| Extra : Using where; Using index                                    | Extra : null                                                         | No    |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
```

Comment: [Please edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65535062/edit) and include the query that you are using along with `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` and `EXPLAIN your query` (for both db.tables) results.

Comment: @tcadidot0 thank you for responding.  I just posted the query.  For SHOW CREATE TABLE and EXPLAIN, do need these for all tables?

Comment: Maybe you can just run `EXPLAIN` on the query you posted above. Just put `EXPLAIN` on top of your query (before `SELECT`) and run it.

Comment: _"I have what I thought was a perfect copy of a database"_ How did you copy the database? Please show the exact SQL command(s) you used.

Comment: @tcadidot0 i added the out of explain for both dbs (same query). Note I reduced the list of samples two just a few.

Comment: I've made edit to your question with just the table showing differences in the `EXPLAIN` as focus. Can you please confirm that this explain result is correct? If its not correct, please edit accordingly. Thanks

Comment: @AaronLisman Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE (each table involved); and B) SHOW INDEX FROM (each table involved); .

Answer (score 0):

you should reanalyze your tables when you insert/delete/update lot of data of a table:

use histogram if your data is not uniformaly distributed.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/analyze-table.html